# Retrieve argument in hook_menu() item url

Tags: 7, ajax, routes

On my custom module, I defined the following hook_menu() function.

```
function motel_events_menu() {

    $items['ajax/pastevents/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Get Past Events',
        'page callback' => '_motel_events_get_pastevents(%)',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}
```

In this function, how can I retrieve the % argument that is passed in 'ajax/pastevents/%' so I can send it to my _motel_events_get_pastevents() function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'page callback' => '_motel_events_get_pastevents(%)',

should be

'page callback' => '_motel_events_get_pastevents',

then insert

```
 'page arguments' => array(2),
```

immediately after. 
ajax is at position 0, pastevent is at position 1 and the wildcard % is at position 2. Counting for arguments starts at 0. The callback function will have a variable to pass in the wildcard value argument.

```
function _motel_events_get_pastevents($arg){
```

Some folks like to use the arg(n) form for arguments as its always present whether declared or not but I tend to use formal declarations.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, this is exactly what I've done.
I didn't say I changed `page callback' => '_motel_events_get_pastevents(%)` to `page callback' => '_motel_events_get_pastevents` in my comment though..
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to defined % in page callback you get url parameter within your function by calling **arg(2)**.